# MySQL: Get all rows if specific value reached after date

Tags: mysql, database, select

In MySQL, I want to find all the rows where the value of a column went to 0 after a specific date.

So, given the data:

```
cat    value     date
a      95        2015-09-01
a      78        2015-10-01
a      0         2015-11-01
a      0         2015-12-01
b      129       2015-09-01
b      230       2015-10-01
b      201       2015-11-01
b      140       2015-12-01
```

In this case, I want to run a query that asks:

> Which categories have 0 value after 10/1/2015 and had a positive value before 11/1/2015?

The result should show category "a".

I suspect is a nested select statement, but haven't quite figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from yourTable where value = 0 and date > '2015-10-01' and cat in (
  select distinct cat where value > 0 and date < '2015-11-1'
)
```

Explanation: you can split the query to two parts - the inner query with the in statement is in charge of getting the cat ID's that were positive before 11/1/15, and the `where value = 0 and date > '2015-10-01'` will give you those that are 0 after 10/1/15

Comment: Works like a charm. I ran into a little issue. I had a concatenated field that I was casting as a date. So, the WHERE clause didn't work using that as my date. I'm sure there's a more elegant workaround, but, I just added a new date column to the field and updated the records to have a real date value. Before, I only had a year col and month col. (Not my original database!)

Answer (score 1):

Building off what Nir Levy said, if you only want the category to be returned, you can select just the distinct values for `cat`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat
FROM stack_test.your_table
WHERE value = 0 AND date > '2015-10-01' AND
cat IN (SELECT cat FROM stack_test.mysql_rows WHERE value > 0 AND date < '2015-11-01');
```

Comment: +1 for this solution. The original solved a big chunk of the problem. I like this to get just at the records I need without all the duplicate info. Thanks a ton! Great add-on solution.

Comment: Thanks! I love these kinds of SQL challenges. Would you mind voting up the answer? I appreciate it!